# By RAW, does Astral Projection allow you to keep your astral body when you leave the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, astral

This spell honestly has me scratching my head with the way it's worded.

[*Astral Projection*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/astral-projection) states the following:

> If you enter a new plane or return to the plane you were on when casting this spell, your body and possessions **are transported** along the silver cord, **allowing** you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane.

As this is worded, can I remain in my *astral body* if I so choose?

To clarify the uses, let me list some potential applications derived from this:

If your *material body* and *astral body* remain apart upon entering a plane other than the Astral Plane, you could:

### 1. **Have a Gore-free clone**:

Use the *astral body* as a gore-free multi-creature version of the Spell [*clone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/clone) that has all astral copies of the gear you had when casting *Astral Projection*. You can stash your real body in a secret, hard to find location (kind of like a phylactery for a lich, only it's your own body) The only "telling" factor is the 1-foot Tether between your shoulders pointing to your body like a compass. You can "safely" run into danger fully knowing your tether to your *material body* is exclusively located on the plane you are on. When you die you return to where you hid your body. Best case scenario nobody managed to find or rob your "bunker". Ideally you (and your associates) have amassed a stash of material components to simply cast *Astral Projection* all over and weasel your way back onto the plane, doing the hiding thing all over again and running back into danger. A long-term plan with lots of bumps (like finding your way through the astral plane to the same portal over and over), but this would work for some BBEG-ish type.

### 2. **Become Practically Immortal**:

#### Keep in mind: Mental health is not factored into this example.

While *Astral Projection* is in effect your *material body* stops aging, decaying requiring sustenance, even air. While you walk the earth within your *astral body* you still require anything your *mortal form* does and age according to the rules of the plane you're on (agelessness is strictly linked to your *material body* and the *Astral Plane*). You can live out a full life in your *astral body*; even ***die of old age*** and you would snap back into your up to then time-locked body, the mind of an old man inside a young body. Assuming the caster has a life expectancy of 50-ish years from when *Astral Projection* was first cast (and he prepares a new set of components for every future casting of the ritual) the caster could - assuming he wakes up in his true body and immediately begins casting the spell again - live up to 438000 lives (as many hours as there are in 50 years), meaning he could theoretically live 17 520 000 years altogether. And that doesn't even factor in the potential of supplying his *material body* with a few *Potions of Longevity* (which have an upper limit of de-aging uses, but still hold the chance of de-aging him 9 times for an average(from 1d6+6, 4+6 = 10) of 90 years).

### 3. Escape from a "BRING HIM TO ME, ALIVE" situation.

Stuck in a bad bind? Does some powerful bad person want you or something stuck in your head? Not a problem if you are currently using your *astral body* and put your real body away safely. *Just kill yourself*. Your soul will return to your real, unharmed (and potentially younger, differently groomed body and the people after you will tear their hair out since [*Locate Creature*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/locate-creature) only goes out for a mile. If your astral body aged significantly / you changed your clothes, hair, etc. they're also going to have a damn hard time recognizing your true self (or your new *astral body* after casting *Astral Projection* yet again). Infinite hijinks.

### 4. Have an "evil" twin

Assume your best friend died. Sad. Further assume he escaped the afterlife to haunt you. Amazing. Just give your *material body* to your ghost pal.(A minor stretch). A *[ghost](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ghost)* can possess your *material body* without any resistance (due to your suspended animation your *material body* is functionally incapacitated, thus failing any checks automatically. Your *material body*'s perfectly operable as per the description of a *ghost*'s *possession* feature, it exclusively affects your body, puppeteering your muscles. Admittedly, now you rely on your already once-killed friend not getting you killed, but that's what you got yourself into by keeping them around anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is unclear.
However, the text of Astral Projection and the Astral Plane seem to indicate that you can.

The Astral Projection spell states:

> Your astral form can freely travel through the Astral Plane and can
> pass through portals there leading to any other plane. If you enter a
> new plane or return to the plane you were on when casting this spell,
> your body and possessions are transported along the silver cord,
> **allowing** you to re-enter your body as you enter the new plane. **Your
> astral form is a separate incarnation. Any damage or other effects
> that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do they
> persist when you return to it.**

From Creating a Multiverse -> Astral Plane -> Astral Projection (Dungeon Master's Guide page 47)

> **Traveling through the Astral Plane by means of the astral projection spell** involves projecting one's consciousness there, **usually in
> search of a gateway to an Outer Plane to visit**. Since the Outer
> Planes are as much spiritual states of being as they are physical
> places, this allows a character **to manifest in an Outer Plane as if
> he or she had physically traveled there**, but as in a dream...
>
> **A character's death-either in the Astral Plane or on the destination
> plane-causes no actual harm**. Only the severing of a character's silver
> cord while on the Astral Plane (**or the death of his or her helpless
> physical body on the Material Plane**) can result in the character's
> true death.

These would seem to indicate that you at least **can** choose to remain in astral body form, so long as your body is somewhere other than the material plane.

To address the questions added since first answering, I will add the following:

### 1- Yes

> Your astral form is a separate incarnation. Any damage or other
> effects that apply to it have no effect on your physical body, nor do
> they persist when you return to it.

### 2- Yes

> The material body you leave behind is unconscious and in a state of
> suspended animation, it doesn't need food or air and doesn't age.

Plus, you would not age at all while this spell is in effect.

From the Dungeon Master's Guide section on the Astral Plane:

> Creatures on the Astral Plane don't age or suffer from hunger or
> thirst. For this reason, humanoids that live on the Astral Plane (such
> as the githyanki) establish outposts on other planes, often the
> Material Plane, so their children can grow to maturity.

### 3- Yes; as long as your cord is intact

> If a creature's original body or its astral form drops to 0 hit
> points, the spell ends for that creature. If the spell ends and the
> silver cord is intact, the cord pulls the creature's astral form back
> to its body, ending its state of suspended animation.

### 4- Too fringe to rule, Ask Your DM

Personally, it seems reasonable to me, for the most part. The question is, what about when you attempt to have your astral body re-merge with your physical body? Thus the requirement of DM ruling.

Comment: What do you base the claim in the last paragraph on? _Astral Projection_ clearly states that _new_ Planes and your own plane (which 99% of times is **the** Material plane) are treated the same way with an inclusive or.

Comment: @Scrawnoisis It does say "**allowing** you to re-enter your body as you enter the **new** plane". So it may indicate the choice is only when entering a new plane, but the wording is admittedly poor.

Comment: Doesn't "new" just mean "not astral" as even returning to the material plane the material plane would be "new" and the astral "old"?

Comment: @J.A.Streich it could, but given that 'enter' is tied to a 'new' plane, and 'return' is used for the original plane, it is inconclusive which way it is intended to be. As I said, it is poorly worded.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my edits! My thinking was much along the same lines. However, as for your comment on scenario 2 we seem to differ. The spell specifies that your _astral body_ is based on your **mortal body**. To my understanding the aspect of non-aging is only affecting your _material body_ and people **on** the _Astral Plane_. If both my _astral_ and _material body_ are on the material or any other aging plane the _astral body_ should age, breathe and eat / drink.

Comment: @Scrawnoisis Honestly, with the way it is worded, it could be either way. I chose to answer the way I did due to the lack of anything saying the astral body ages, needs food/water/air, or needs rest; and because of it starting in the Astral Plane, and being separate from a physical body, but at least starting identical to the physical body to start.

Comment: I see, that is a fair point.

Comment: @Scrawnoisis due to your math, I tried some of my own, using solely PHB content. half-orc monk, level 17 at age 20; assuming aging astral body; 55 years per astral body, 54 years for physical; 3 hours for physical for every 2 lifetimes of astral; results in final age of 17,344,820 years.

Comment: @Journer slight addendum on that, actually. We're forgetting the limit of the amounts of spell slots usable in a given day. High level wizards and even a Lich (MM) have only one Lvl 9 Slot per long rest. Without some artifact or means to recover while your _material body_ is marketly unable to rest this shortens the lives-span of the half-orc monk to 3000 years.

Comment: @Scrawnoisis no spell slots needed, just Ki points, due to being a monk; and they have 17 points per short rest at level 17, while Astral Projection only costs 8 (so 2 castings per short rest).

Comment: @Journer Ah, never you mind me then.